# Attempting to hide <td> from C# causes error: The name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview, webforms

**Goal:** I am trying to (conditionally) hide a value depending on my settings

**What I've tried:**
I first tried to do it like I have in other places, but I was hiding asp controls like Panel. This is just html.

When looking this up, it was mentioned to add:
1. id
2. runat=server

**Problem:** I tried these, but I am getting the error:

> "The name 'groupid' does not exist in the current context"

---

**CODE:**

**.aspx:**

```
<td id="groupid" runat="server">
```

**.cs:**

```
groupid.Visible = true;
```

---

is in an ItemTemplate for a asp:ListView:

```
<asp:ListView>
<LayoutTemplate>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
```

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Is the TD in a Repeater/GridView of some sorts?

Comment: Is td an ASP control?

Comment: @Dai : VisualStudio 2017.

Comment: @VDWWD : its in the HTML inside of a ItemTemplate associated to a Listview.

Comment: @SalomonZhang : I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

`td` is table cell in HTML.

In ASP.NET you can use `<asp:TableCell>` which is equivalent to `td`.

Give the Id to `<asp:TableCell>` instead of using `<td>`

Does this solve your problem?

**Updates:**

C#:

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.FindControl("tdotherItem").Visible = false;
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td runat="server" id="myCol" visible='<%# (bool)Eval("otherItem") %>'>
                <%# Eval("other") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Notice the use of `visible ='<%# %>'`

Comment: `<td runat="server">` maps to `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell`, using the `<asp:...>` controls is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Dai are you using id="" to identify it? I tried this and got the following error: "The name '' does not exist in the current context" in my c# file.

Comment: @salomonzhang : I used your solution but am still getting the error: "The name 'otheritem' does not exist in the current context"

This is how I tried to use it:
.aspx:
<ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
  <td style="width: 20%;"><%# Item.Some_Item %></td>
  <asp:TableCell ID="otheritem"> <%# Item.Other_Item %> </asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell ID="lastitem"> <%# Item.Last_Item %> </asp:TableCell>

  
.cs: 
if(aaa) { otheritem.Visible = true; }
else { lastitem.Visible = true;

Comment: @seesharp You need runat="server" as well. Try `<asp:TableCell ID="otheritem" runat="server">`

Comment: @SalomonZhang I noticed that as well, when I added it I still get the error. This is whats currently there:  <asp:TableCell ID="otheritem" runat="server">. I've tried it with <% Item.Other_Item %> and without. The c# is in a method that gets called for the ListView : public IQueryable<Program.Data.View> someMethod_GetData()
{
  try
       {
          if (isAAA())
          {
   otheritem.Visible = true;

Answer (score 0):

If the Control is in a ListView (or a Repeater, GridView etc.) you have to use FindControl. And because you use a "normal" td with runat=server you need to cast it to an `HtmlTableCell`.

```
HtmlTableCell htc = ListView1.Items[1].FindControl("groupid") as HtmlTableCell;

htc.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red");
//or
htc.Visible = false;
```

Although I would recommend against hiding individual table cells. This can give weird results in a browser.

Comment: The reason I have a conditional is: I have a Field to display on the page, lets call it "Field1". Depending on who the client is, there is a different database Column name in the View that should be displayed for field one. For Client A I want "ColumnA" , for Client B I want "ColumnB"